# Most common translation of "Happy New Year!"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras

Is "Happy New Year!" more commonly translated as "¡Feliz Año Nuevo!" or "¡Próspero Año Nuevo!"? Are the two basically synonyms, or is there a difference between the two?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd say "Próspero Año Nuevo" is more  formal and not really use in speech. You'll find it in Xmas cards, etc.

"Feliz Año Nuevo" is used but for a more informal form you can just say "Feliz Año". "Feliz Año" is what you hear everywhere these days in Spain.

¡Feliz Año!

Answer (score 2):

Si sólo estás felicitando el nuevo año, como en *"**Happy New Year!**"*, lo más habitual es decir "**¡Feliz Año Nuevo!**" o simplemente "**¡Feliz Año!**".

No obstante, al felicitar en la misma frase tanto la Navidad como el Año Nuevo, es cuando se dice "**¡Feliz Navidad y Próspero Año Nuevo!**", en parte para desear prosperidad además de felicidad, pero más que nada porque decir "feliz" dos veces no queda tan bien.
Esta última fórmula es más formal, y se parece un poco a la canción: *"We wish you a **Merry Christmas and a Happy New Year**"*. En realidad, "¡Próspero Año Nuevo!" por sí solo no se suele decir, es siempre como parte de esta fórmula.

Answer (score 1):

I would say `Happy New Year!` should be translated as `¡Feliz Año Nuevo!`

`Próspero año nuevo` should be translated as `Prosperous new year`.

It's very common to say `Te deseo una feliz navidad y un próspero año nuevo` (I wish you a merry Christmas and a prosperous new year.)

Comment: I can't recall ever hearing "Prosperous New Year" in English and I don't see why there's more need to translate literally when it comes to this phrase. But maybe they do say this in English in other countries?

Comment: @hippietrail I haven't heard "Prosperous New Year" used before either (except for myself) but omitting prosperity or translating it as happiness is, in my opinion, a drastic change. I am okay, for example, with translating "run-of-the-mill" as "normalito" since the meaning is preserved but that's not the case here.

Comment: But I don't think we're translating the words, we're translating a greeting. For instance, you can't translate "echar de menos" if you translate the words.

Comment: @hippietrail If I want to wish you both, happiness and prosperity on the coming year, how should I phrase it?

Comment: Well in that case it wouldn't be a set phrase in either language so you would just translate it literally.